# crash when object goes out of scope - glibc detected free(): invalid pointer in std::set

Tags: c++, valgrind

After making some changes to (other parts) of a large application, I get the run time "glibc: double free or corruption (out)" below when the **ExtInputList** object goes out of scope.  I don't understand why.

(and if you move the declaration to a higher/outer scope the error still happens when the object goes out of scope.  Just later)

Shouldn't the '=' in *mExternalInputs = ExtInputList* copy the whole list into the object, leaving it ok for *ExtInputList* to be destroyed? (and there is no new/delete anywhere either)

I've been on this all day and out of ideas.  I've pulled the code into its own file and it works fine; just not in the big system.  What can I look out for or investigate further?

Many thanks in advance!

```
typedef std::list<TExternalInputs> TExtInputList;

if (1)
{
    TRACE(("%N noOfExtInput: %d\n", noOfExtInput));
    TExtInputList   ExtInputList;
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfExtInput; i++)
    {
        TExternalInputs ExtInput;
        TRACE(("%N Reading external input data\n"));
        bool found = stream.readObject(ExtInput, i);
        TRACE(("%N stream.readObject found=%d\n", found));
        ExtInput.dump();
        ExtInputList.push_back(ExtInput);
    }
    TRACE(("%N pre  mExternalInputs = ExtInputList\n"));
    mExternalInputs = ExtInputList;
    TRACE(("%N post mExternalInputs = ExtInputList\n"));
}  <==== error is here
TRACE(("%N post if() \n"));
```

stream.readObject, defined as *bool readObject(BaseClassToTExternalInputs&, long)* and it **does return** a valid object as evidenced by the dump().  GDB also shows a valid object:

```
 (gdb) bt
 #0  0xb7770d14 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
 #1  0x008eeb11 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
 #2  0x008f03ea in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
 #3  0x0092e9d5 in __libc_message () from /lib/libc.so.6
 #4  0x00934e31 in malloc_printerr () from /lib/libc.so.6
 #5  0x00937571 in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
 #6  0x46465552 in operator delete(void*) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
 #7  0x080503a6 in TExternalInputs::~TExternalInputs (this=0x9089a48, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at ../../include/db/DvDbPortConfig.h:71
 #8  0xb7521192 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<TExternalInputs>::destroy (this=0xbfbedde7, __p=0x9089a48)
     at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:115
 #9  0xb751f374 in std::_List_base<TExternalInputs, std::allocator<TExternalInputs> >::_M_clear (this=0xbfbedeb0)
     at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/list.tcc:76
 #10 0xb751d595 in std::_List_base<TExternalInputs, std::allocator<TExternalInputs> >::~_List_base (this=0xbfbedeb0,
 __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
     at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_list.h:360
 #11 0xb751cbe1 in std::list<TExternalInputs, std::allocator<TExternalInputs> >::~list (this=0xbfbedeb0,
 __in_chrg=<value optimized out>)
     at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_list.h:418
 #12 0xb7445080 in DvDbPortConfig::deserialize (this=0x8f4d240, stream=...) at DvDbPortConfig.cpp:185
 #13 0xb73961f9 in DvCfgStream::read (this=0xbfbee158, name=0xb74817b9 "PortConfig", obj=..., index=1) at DvCfgStream.cpp:262
 #14 0x08050256 in DvCsrOutputStream::writeObject (this=0xbfbee158, obj=..., i=1) at ../../include/csr/DvCsrStream.h:266
 #15 0xb727f931 in DvCfgRackManager::deserialize (this=0x8952908, stream=...) at DvCfgRackManager.cpp:557
 #16 0xb73961f9 in DvCfgStream::read (this=0xbfbee254, name=0xb7318414 "DvStation", obj=..., index=-1) at DvCfgStream.cpp:262
 #17 0x08050256 in DvCsrOutputStream::writeObject (this=0xbfbee254, obj=..., i=-1) at ../../include/csr/DvCsrStream.h:266
 #18 0x0804f827 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfbee3a4) at DvMain.cpp:154 (gdb) frame 12
 #12 0xb7445080 in DvDbPortConfig::deserialize (this=0x8f4d240, stream=...) at DvDbPortConfig.cpp:185 185                    
 TRACE(("%N post mExternalInputs = ExtInputList\n")); (gdb) p
 ExtInputList $1 = std::list = {   [0] = {<DvCsrSerializable> =
 {_vptr.DvCsrSerializable = 0x8056328}, m_slotID = 1, m_input =
 std::list = {[0] = "ASI", [1] = <error reading variable> }
```

Further, *ExtInputList.push_back(ExtInput)* should be *copying* the ExtInput object, right? So it would seem the ExtInput object is being free'd by someone else.

Now, TExternalInputs is a simple class:

```
class  TExternalInputs : public DvCsrSerializable
{
    public:
       Dv::TSlotNumber  m_slotID;
       TInputList       m_input;    // list of std::strings

       TExternalInputs() { }
       virtual ~TExternalInputs() {}

       void dump()
       {
           printf("TExternalInputs slot: %d\n", m_slotID);
           for (TInputList::iterator it=m_input.begin(); it != m_input.end(); ++it)
               printf("  - '%s'\n", (*it).c_str() );

       }
};
```

**Runtime Error (demangled for your convenience):**

```
DvDbPortConfig::deserialize()
DvCfgStream::read SlotDataDvCfgStream SlotData idx: 0 created
DvCfgStream::read created new node for 'SlotData'. pCfg == 0
DvDbPortConfig.cpp noOfExtInput: 1
DvDbPortConfig.cpp Reading external input data
DvCfgStream::read ExternalInputsDvCfgStream ExternalInputs idx: 0 created
DvCfgStream::read created new node for 'ExternalInputs'. pCfg == 0
DvDbPortConfig.cpp stream.readObject found=1
TExternalInputs slot: 1
  - 'ASI'
DvDbPortConfig.cpp pre  mExternalInputs = ExtInputList
DvDbPortConfig.cpp post mExternalInputs = ExtInputList
*** glibc detected *** ./DvMain: double free or corruption (out): 0x0a2149e8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========/lib/libc.so.6[0x934e31]
/lib/libc.so.6[0x937571]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(operator delete(void*)+0x22)[0x46465552]
./DvMain(TExternalInputs::~TExternalInputs()+0x28)[0x80503a6]
/usr/local/dvstation/lib/libdvlog.so.6(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<TExternalInputs>::destroy(TExternalInputs*)+0x18)[0xb756f192]
/usr/local/dvstation/lib/libdvlog.so.6(std::_List_base<TExternalInputs, std::allocator<TExternalInputs> >::_M_clear()+0x56)[0xb756d374]
/usr/local/dvstation/lib/libdvlog.so.6(std::_List_base<TExternalInputs, std::allocator<TExternalInputs> >::~_List_base()+0x1f)[0xb756b595]
/usr/local/dvstation/lib/libdvlog.so.6(std::list<TExternalInputs, std::allocator<TExternalInputs> >::~list()+0x1d)[0xb756abe1]
```

**Update**
I've also tried valgrind to find the problem.  No joy:

```
vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xC5 0xF9 0x6E 0x45
==29593== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x406e9a8.
==29593==    at 0x406E9A8: std::tr1::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy::_M_next_bkt(unsigned int) const (hashtable_policy.h:460)
==29593==    by 0x434D522: std::tr1::_Hashtable<DvDbDataBaseObject*, DvDbDataBaseObject*, std::allocator<DvDbDataBaseObject*>, std::_Identity<DvDbDataBaseObject*>, equalp<DvDbDataBase
[...]
==29593== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==29593== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==29593== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==29593==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==29593==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==29593== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==29593==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==29593==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==29593== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==29593== probably kill your program.
```

**Update II**
I've removed the 'virtual' keyword from the destructor of the containing class and now the problem is gone.

Why?  I have no idea.

Comment: Is `TExtInputList` following [the rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? What is the definition of `TExtInputList`?

Comment: I've added the declaration of TExtInputList above.  For the 3/5/0 rule, does the "virtual ~TSlotData() { }" count as a "custom destructor"? (and therefore needing the other stuff to be implemented? Right now neither this class nor its base have those defined...

Comment: I wouldn't count an empty destructor as enough to invoke "the rule". You could use a tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you locate possible pointer problems.

Comment: Yup, tried valgrind.  It dies with "unhandled instruction", which seems to be a common problem. Transcript added to question.

Comment: I would tip on some memory corruption issues (buffer overflow ?), which would mean that removing the virtual only hides another problem (which caused the vtable pointer to be overwritten)

Comment: Yup, that could certainly be true.  But given the size of the code, I'm not sure at all how to start to find it...